# Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532) after function check with a function returning boolean

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, next.js

I'm using react and react-query, basically I'm trying to render a Hero component with data from a API call.

If I use this code I don't have any error:

```
        {!query && data && data?.pages && data.pages[0]?.results[0] ? (
          <Hero
            text={data.pages[0].results[0].overview}
            title={data.pages[0].results[0].title}
            imgUrl={
              data?.pages[0]?.results[0]?.backdrop_path
                ? IMAGE_BASE_URL +
                  BACKDROP_SIZE +
                  data.pages[0].results[0].backdrop_path
                : "./no_image.jpg"
            }
          />
        ) : null}
```

But when using this code(with a helper function returning a boolean) I have the error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)

```
        {hasDataResults(query, data) ? (
          <Hero
            text={data.pages[0].results[0].overview}
            title={data.pages[0].results[0].title}
            imgUrl={
              data?.pages[0]?.results[0]?.backdrop_path
                ? IMAGE_BASE_URL +
                  BACKDROP_SIZE +
                  data.pages[0].results[0].backdrop_path
                : "./no_image.jpg"
            }
          />
        ) : null}
```

Function helper:

```
const hasDataResults = (
  query: string,
  data: InfiniteData<Movies> | undefined
): boolean =>
  Boolean(!query && data && data?.pages && data.pages[0]?.results[0]);
```

Doesn't the function **hasDataResults** have the same output?
please help

Expecting the error go away.
Tried adding more conditionals within the helper function.

Comment: What object exactly can be `undefined`? Which line throws the error?

Comment: Text and title props

Comment: You marked your data as `data: InfiniteData<Movies> | undefined` so I guess it can be `undefined`

Comment: But the data object, which is returned by react-query has that type. InfinityData<Movies> | undefined

Comment: If `data.pages` would be an empty array then your `data.pages[0]` will return `undefined`

Comment: You are correct that logically they are the same. However when the compiler sees something like `if (a && a.b && a.b.c)` or `if (a?.b?.c)` then in *the scope of that block* it knows `a.b.c` can't fail. But it can't follow from the call to the helper function that the access is safe: it just isn't smart enough for that (or more precisely, it can't do it fast enough to keep the compile times reasonable).

Comment: @Konrad typescript won't catch index out of bounds errors. If you type something as an array you can index any number without the possibly undefined warning. That is unless you explicitly type the contents as being possibly undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Typescript won't look inside your functions for type guards, but you can declare a function using a type predicate: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

This tells Typescript exactly what your boolean return value means. The following says that returning a true value indicates that `data` is of type `InfiniteData<Movies>`.

```js
const hasDataResults = (
  query: string,
  data: InfiniteData<Movies> | undefined
): data is InfiniteData<Movies> =>
  Boolean(!query && data && data?.pages && data.pages[0]?.results[0]);
```

---

If you need to also say that the `pages` and `results` properties are defined, you can do that in the predicate as well. You can add the types of arrays in too, I just don't know what they are.

```js
const hasDataResults = (
  query: string,
  data: InfiniteData<Movies> | undefined
): data is InfiniteData<Movies> & {pages: {results: []}[]} =>
  Boolean(!query && data && data?.pages && data.pages[0]?.results[0]);
```

Comment: I understand, but, I'm still having the error

Comment: Does your `InfiniteData` type contain possibly undefined properties?

Comment: @Jorge edited to show you how to say the properties are defined as well.